# How to insert simple array into table field using mybatis annotation

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, innodb, mybatis

My class field looks like

```
private int[] points = new int[]{1,1,1,1};
```

My innoDb table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `points` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT '0' 
)
```

I try insert row into table thith this mapper (i'm using annotation)

```
@Insert({
        "REPLACE INTO test (points)",
        "values (#points},javaType=java.util.Array,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler)"
})
```

and getting the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property points`

How i can correctly insert this array in one field?
I could convert an array into a string, but I want to use the mybatis opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a typo in the snippet for Mybatis parameter, on curly braces {}:

```
VALUES ( {#points,javaType=java.util.Array,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler}
)
```

Furthermore, a custom ArrayTypeHandler implementation could be required, either for formatting as here it is stored as a String(Varchar), or if it is stored as SQL Array, then dependent on environment: DB Type/driver, pooled connection, application server ...